# How do I change the drop down button color when clicked Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, button, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I installed this Bootstrap drop down button https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/ (the second one with the *"a"* element, so my "button" is really a link) and everything works perfectly, except when I try to change the background color of the button when it is clicked; it remains the default grey that comes with the button as well as the light grey border that appears. I want to change the background color when the button is clicked.

Here is my code:

(Just to`explain, my html is in *li* because I use the drop down button as a menu item for the navigation, and I am using *span* instead of *div* because it will only align properly with *span* instead of forming a block.)

html:

```
<span class="dropdown show">

    <li>

        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" 
        id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
        aria-expanded="false" onclick="myFunction()">Help</a>

    <span class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </span>
    </li>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
    #color-change {
    background-color: #00ffba;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("color-change");
}
```

I've looked online and tried other ways of changing the background color when clicking, but to no avail, I reckon it might be something to do with the list element and/or span element interfering with the Javascript, along with interfering with Bootstrap, but my Javascript is also likely wrong.

Thanks!

`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this via simple CSS. Add one class in the  tag.

```
 <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle customButton" href="#" role="button"
       id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
       aria-expanded="false">Help</a>
```

CSS

```
.show > .customButton:focus{
background: #00ffba !important ;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  border: none !important;

}
.customButton{
  box-shadow:none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

If you want all your btn-secondary to be same color when clicked then you can add the css directly to that class as follows:

```
.show > .btn-secondary:focus{
background: #00ffba !important ;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  border: none !important;

}
.btn-secondary{
  box-shadow:none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

Codepen link :https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzWrYr

Comment: Thanks, your code got it to change color, but it has the opposite effect of what I wanted, the button still changes to grey when I click it, but if I click it again, (when the drop down menu is out) it changes to my desired color (and it still has that grey border after I click it) How do I get it to change colors when I first click it? Neutral button: https://imgur.com/heJ0EiH    When clicked: https://imgur.com/Tf4NO1K     When clicked again: https://imgur.com/YrIKFac  Thanks!

Comment: @RGao , I have updated my original answer, You should remove "show" from <span class="dropdown show"> show class is dynamically added by bootstrap, when the button is clicked. I have also included a code pen link in my original answer. Please check it out. Thanks !!

Comment: @SjanLamsai It works now, thanks. However, when I click the button and hold down it is still dark grey, many people click slowly so they will still see this, which is a problem. The buttons also get a 100px border radius (basically oval) when I click off the button and hold to get rid of the dropdown. Lastly, I still can't adjust the padding.

Answer (score 0):

this code will work for you. change ID and colour for you.

```
$('body').on('click', '#id-of-button-to-change-background', function(){

    $(this).css('background-color', 'colour-to-change-will-go-here');

})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion and put it in codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaQLoB but it still doesn't work, I've also tried replacing the $('body)' and $(this) with my button class, and I've also tried with the dropdownMenuLink id but it still does not work.